# Analytics for Web Part Usage (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-administration, google-analytics

#### My Question

Out of the custom apps and web parts listed in the tenant app catalog, is it possible to get usage analytics for those custom apps and web parts?

Ultimately, I am looking to see which web part gets loaded the most on the tenant-wide level. It would also be nice to see the site collection and subsite scope too.

I am looking for a solution that does **NOT** include modifying the code for the web parts.

*Please note, I have Google Analytics actively running in my tenant.*

#### Desired Insight:

Ex, In your tenant, the "Custom Events" web part was loaded 1234 times over the last 30 days. The "Custom Profile Image" web part was loaded 200 times over the last 30 days.

#### Proposed Solutions:

1. Add a unique server call in the custom code of each web part and analyze the traffic/requests.
2. Use SharePoint analytics or Google Analytics to find the most popular pages, then leverage the `?maintenancemode=true` query string to find the web parts on those popular pages.
3. Out of a list of the top viewed site pages, use the REST API to get the page content from `CanvasContent1`. The data includes the ID's for all the web parts on the page. Then you can convert the ID's for each web part to their alias name/title.

> ```
> https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=Title,CanvasContent1,FileLeafRef&$filter=FileLeafRef%20eq%20%27Home.aspx%27
> ```